# TradingView filters

Tags: typescript

In Pine Script, by creating a custom indicator, you can potentially filter out a significant number of charts based on your desired conditions. This allows for a highly tailored approach to chart analysis.

ps:

C>L1 AND O>L1 AND C<H1 AND O<H1 etc

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, well, it's no question.